# mod_rewrite if you use an expression all over the place, can you put it in a "variable"?

Tags: mod-rewrite

If I use the following like 50 times in my htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^(bla|blo|bli|blu|bloi|bkdo|doid|boidi|woekj|dfpo8ds)/?$ /section_index.php?sectionurl=$1 [L]

is it then possible to just put bla|blo|bli|blu|bloi|bkdo|doid|boidi|woekj|dfpo8ds in a variable instead of using it again in every line? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Give us an example of how you think a variable would solve your problem.

Comment: Problem is that I am using that rewriterule line many, many times in the htaccess file. Everytime I have to write the entire bla|blo|bli|blu|bloi|bkdo|doid|boidi|woekj|dfpo8ds piece again. So I'd like to just put that in a variable and start doing this:

RewriteRule ^(MVARIABLE)/?$ /section_index.php?sectionurl=$1 [L]

Comment: But why do you use the same expression in more than one rule? Or is this expression just a sub-expression (maybe a prefix) of another expression? Again, an example of such rules would be helpful.

Comment: It's only a subexpression. I use it like this: ^(MVARIABLE)/?$, and the next rule says ^(MVARIABLE)/someotherstuffhere?$ and the next one ^(MVARIABLE)/yetotherstuff?$ and so on...

Comment: So as background: the site has a whole bunch of url paths that start with /bla/ or /blo/ etc., and then they are the same, like /bla/blogs/ and /blo/blogs/, and so on

Answer (score 1):

You could set an environment variable:

```
RewriteRule ^(bla|blo|bli|blu|bloi|bkdo|doid|boidi|woekj|dfpo8ds)/?$ /section_index.php?sectionurl=$1 [L,E=FOOBAR:$1]
```

The value is now accessible with `%{ENV:FOOBAR}`.

---

**Edit**    Another way would be to process the request in steps and chain the rules:

```
# first path segment
RewriteRule ^(bla|blo|bli|blu|bloi|bkdo|doid|boidi|woekj|dfpo8ds)/?([^/].*)?$ $2?sectionurl=$1 [QSA,C]
# second path segment
RewriteRule ^(blog|foo)/?([^/].*)?$ $2?arg1=$1 [QSA,C]
# third path segment
RewriteRule ^(bar|baz)/?([^/].*)?$ $2?arg2=$1 [QSA,C]
# last rule
RewriteRule ^$ section_index.php [L,QSA]
```

But as you use PHP, you could also use PHP to parse the request path, for example:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
$argNames = array('sectionurl', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
foreach ($segments as $i => $segment) {
    if (isset($argNames[$i])) {
        $_GET[$argNames[$i]] = $segment;
    }
}
var_dump($_GET);
```

Now you just need to send every request to that PHP file by using this rule:

```
# exclude requests for existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, this is what I'm trying: RewriteRule ^(%{ENV:FOOBAR})/?$ /section_index.php?sectionurl=$1 [L]

Comment: You cannot use variables in the search pattern. But you could use an additional `RewriteCond` like as `RewriteCond %{ENV:FOOBAR}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(bla|blo|bli|blu|bloi|bkdo|doid|boidi|woekj|dfpo8ds)/\1`. But that’s not quite elegant.